# Goのhttptestにおいてhandlerに値を渡したい

Tags: go, テスト

golangで下記のようなhttpのテストを書いているのですが、httptestにおいてhandlerにRESTのurl（`/item/{item_id}`)に埋め込んだ値(`item_id`)を渡すにはどうしたらいいですか？

テストコード

```
func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
    handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        itemID := vars["item_id"]
        fmt.Println("itemID: ", itemID)
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/item/{item_id}", handler)
    testserver := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(handler))
    defer testserver.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", testserver.URL, nil)
    if err != nil {}

    var client http.Client
    client.Do(req)
}
```

コマンド

$ go test ./... -v

実行結果

```
=== RUN   TestHandler
itemID:  
--- PASS: TestHandler (0.00s)
```

例えば、この実行結果の部分で`itemID`を出力させたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gorilla/mux` パッケージを使うのでしたら、`$GOPATH/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux_test.go` に参考にしてテストコードを書いてみてはどうでしょうか。以下はその一例です。

**handler_test.go**

```golang
func TestHandler(t *testing.T) {
  handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    itemID := vars["item_id"]
    fmt.Println("itemID: ", itemID)
  }

  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/item/{item_id}", handler)

  req, _ := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://localhost/item/no_001", nil)
  res := new(http.ResponseWriter)
  router.ServeHTTP(*res, req)
}
```

**実行結果**

```bash
$ go test -v handler_test.go
=== RUN   TestHandler
itemID:  no_001
--- PASS: TestHandler (0.00s)
```